# How do I install and run Neo4j on Windows 10?

Tags: installation, neo4j

I am totally new to this, and using it as part of a class that provided no instructions. . .

I have Windows 10.

I have downloaded the Community version of Neo4j here: https://neo4j.com/download-center/#community

Then what do I do?  Talk to me like I'm the brainless Scarecrow  from the Wizard of Oz.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow in the installation instructions from neo4j?  As of Sept 2020, the link is https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/. If so, what problem are you having?

Comment: @mirtheil, I can follow the directions to Step 3.  Then at Step 4, I don't know what to do. Every other time I've downloaded and installed a program, the download includes an .exe file that I click to install.  With the Community Version of Neo4j, there is no such .exe  file.  I'm following the "2.5.1. Windows console application", because I have Windows 10.

Comment: @mirtheil, aha, wait a minute.  I did complete Step 4 as well.  I get an error saying "Neo4j cannot be started using java version 1.8.0_261"  So I need an older version of Java?

Comment: And that's a different question.  I know when I tried to run the Community Server version on my Windows 10 box, I got "WARNING: ERROR! Neo4j cannot be started using java version 1.8.0_172
WARNING: * Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 11, OpenJDK(TM) 11 to run Neo4j Server." which tells me what version of Java to run.  You need to look at the full error / warnings to see what it's telling you and install the appropriate version of Java / JDK.

Comment: @mirtheil, My full error says, "WARNING: ERROR! Neo4j cannot be started using java version 1.8.0_261     WARNING: *Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 11, Open JDK(TM) 11 to run Neo4j server."   So I need Java 11. I go to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html, download and run the installation.  Then when I go to the Windows 10 CMD, navigate to the Neo4j folder and run "bin/neo4j console" I am still seeing the same error about the Java version.  It seems like the newer version of Java is still installed, even though I ran the Java 11 installer?

Comment: Eh.  I guess I got it running.  I'm just not used to programs without an exe installer.  :)  Even after I downloaded and installed Java 11 (from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html), I still could not get Neo4j to work and still got the exact same error as before.  I had to uninstall all Java versions, then reinstall Java 11 before I could start Neo4j with the CMD prompt.